# Cannot perform reading from pipe in C?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

I am writing a code to interact with an application involving reading and writing to the application. Here is the code: the first one - namely input.c interacts with the second one - namely app.c

```
//input.c    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0

void error(char* msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}

void got_here(char* msg){
    printf("Got_here:%s\n",msg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp){
    int fd_parent[2];
    int fd_child[2]; // for parent and child to write respectively
    if(pipe(fd_parent) < 0 | pipe(fd_child) < 0){
        error("Fail to create a pipe"); /// just an error-handle function
    }
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child < 0){
        error("Fail to create a child"); 
    }
    else if(child == 0){
        dup2(fd_child[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fd_parent[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd_parent[WRITE]);
        close(fd_child[READ]);
        char str[100] = "./app";
        execve(str, argv,envp);
        close(fd_parent[READ]);
        close(fd_child[WRITE]);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        close(fd_parent[READ]);
        close(fd_child[WRITE]);

        FILE* stream = fdopen(fd_child[READ], "r");
        FILE* stream_write = fdopen(fd_parent[WRITE], "w");

        char str[20];
        char menu[4] = "10\n";
        fread(str,sizeof(char), 20, stream); // Here is where the problem lies
        got_here("after read");  // it does not get here
        fwrite(menu, sizeof(char), 3, stream_write);
        fflush(stream_write);

        fclose(stream);
        fclose(stream_write);
        printf("Parent Done\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the application code (I only include the main for shorter code):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp){
    char str[10];
    printf("- Select Menu -1\n");
    printf("1. Play Lotto\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

After running, my program just paused at the `fread()` line where it is supposed to finish reading and write to the application. The interesting is if I omit either the `scanf()` or `printf()` in the second program it works fine. I try change the place of the `fwrite` and `fread` but the problem is still there. I think it is buffer-related problem, but the application I am trying to interact with is not of my permission to change, so I cannot include `fflush` or something.

Is my guess right or there is another explanation for this? And how to get over this problem?

Comment: regarding: `execve(str, argv,envp);`  1) if execve() returns, then an error occurred. so should be immediately calling `perror()` before anything else. 2) a return value of 0 (typically) indicates success.  suggest using: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )l`

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered

Comment: It seems that the problem does not lie in `execve` since it does not  return anything after I put `perror` in the code. It still paused all the same.

Comment: regarding: `if(pipe(fd_parent) < 0 | pipe(fd_child) < 0)`  This is a bit wise OR.  The statement should be using a logical OR `||`

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing these statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` `#include <string.h>` and `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: Note that the sequence `execve(str, argv,envp);
        close(fd_parent[READ]);
        close(fd_child[WRITE]);
        return 0;` doesn't close the 'other ends' of the pipes unless the command fails to execute.  You should have the `close()` calls before the `execve()`.  You should probably report an error after the `execve()` and you should exit (return) with a non-zero status — the child program did not succeed, after all.

Comment: After you've used `fdopen()` you should `fclose()` the file streams rather than `close()` the file descriptors.

Comment: I have updated the code due to your suggestion but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command to modify the buffering options of the program at the other end of a pipe. In order to do this in C, you can write:

```
char str[100] = "./app";

char **new_argv = malloc (sizeof (char *) * (argc + 9));
new_argv[0] = "stdbuf";
new_argv[1] = "-i";
new_argv[2] = "0";
new_argv[3] = "-o";
new_argv[4] = "L";
new_argv[5] = "-e";
new_argv[6] = "L";
new_argv[7] = str;
memcpy (&new_argv[8], &argv[1], argc - 1);
new_argv[argc + 8] = NULL;

execvp ("stdbuf", new_argv);
error ("execvp");
```

or if you don't really need to pass the arguments of the parent on to the child, then:

```
execlp ("stdbuf", "stdbuf", "-i", "0", "-o", "L", "-e", "L", "./app", NULL);
error ("execlp");
```

The `stdbuf` command uses LD_PRELOAD to load a library (`libstdbuf.so`) into the other program. This library does the trick of modifying the buffering options. You can avoid the use of `stdbuf` and set the preload options yourself before exec(). You can also write your own library and preload that instead. But using the `stdbuf` is probably the easiest option, if you have this command available.

See also [stdbuf source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/stdbuf.c)

Here's the full modified example of your code:

```
//input.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0

void error (char *msg)
{
    perror (msg);
    exit (-1);
}

void got_here (char *msg)
{
    printf ("Got_here: %s\n", msg);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    int fd_parent[2];
    int fd_child[2]; // for parent and child to write respectively
    pid_t child;

    if (pipe (fd_parent) < 0) {
        error ("pipe(fd_parent)");
    }

    if (pipe (fd_child) < 0) {
        error ("pipe(fd_child)");
    }

    child = fork ();

    if (child < 0) {

        error ("fork");

    } else if (child == 0) {

        dup2 (fd_child[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2 (fd_parent[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        close (fd_parent[WRITE]);
        close (fd_child[READ]);

        char str[100] = "./app";

        char **new_argv = malloc (sizeof (char *) * (argc + 9));
        new_argv[0] = "stdbuf";
        new_argv[1] = "-i";
        new_argv[2] = "0";
        new_argv[3] = "-o";
        new_argv[4] = "L";
        new_argv[5] = "-e";
        new_argv[6] = "L";
        new_argv[7] = str;
        memcpy (&new_argv[8], &argv[1], argc - 1);
        new_argv[argc + 8] = NULL;

        execvp ("stdbuf", new_argv);
        error ("execvp");

        close (fd_parent[READ]);
        close (fd_child[WRITE]);

        return 0;

    } else {

        close (fd_parent[READ]);
        close (fd_child[WRITE]);

        FILE *stream = fdopen (fd_child[READ], "r");
        FILE *stream_write = fdopen (fd_parent[WRITE], "w");

        char str[20];
        char menu[4] = "10\n";
        int res = fread (str, sizeof (char), 20, stream); // Here is where the problem lies
        printf ("res = %d\n", res);
        got_here ("after read");  // it does not get here
        fwrite (menu, sizeof (char), 3, stream_write);
        fflush (stream_write);

        fclose (stream);
        fclose (stream_write);
        printf ("Parent Done\n");

        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Really sorry for my late reply. But even using `stdbuf` does not fix the problem. Now Im really puzzled and do not know where I did wrong.

Comment: I've added a full example of input.c, that works for me with the simple app.c provided by you.